# Matlab fft function

Tags: matlab, fft, sampling

The code below is from the Matlab 2011a help about fft function.
I *think* there is a problem here : why do they multiply t(1:50) by Fs, and then say it's time in millisecond ? Certainly, it happens to be true in this very particular case, but change the value of Fs to, say, 2000, and it won't work anymore, obviously because of this factor of 2. *Right* ?  Quite misleading, isn't it ? What do I miss ?

```
Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 1000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
% Sum of a 50 Hz sinusoid and a 120 Hz sinusoid
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t); 
y = x + 2*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise
plot(Fs*t(1:50),y(1:50))
title('Signal Corrupted with Zero-Mean Random Noise')
xlabel('time (milliseconds)')
```

Clearer with this :

```
fs = 2000;          % Sampling frequency
T = 1 / fs;         % Sample time
L = 1000;           % Length of signal
t2 = (0:L-1)*T;     % Time vector
f = 50;             % signal frequency
s2 = sin(2*pi*f*t2);
figure, plot(fs*t2(1:50),s2(1:50)); % NOT good
figure, plot(t2(1:50),s2(1:50));    % good
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't miss anything. This is a typical bad practice of not having units as comments for each line. For example,

```
 Fs=1000;          % in [Hz]
 T=1/Fs;           % [sec]
 L = 1000;         % Length of signal
 t = (0:L-1)*T;    % Time vector
```

then, the time vector has units of 1/1000 seconds, or milliseconds... (each element is 1 ms).
In the other case Fs=2000 %[Hz], which makes the time vector to have units of 1/2000 seconds...

Comment: So to be safe, I will always do plot(t2(1:50),s2(1:50)); thanks

Comment: @CTZStef To be really safe, understand the units of the vector you are plotting...

Comment: Well that is were I actually ended up, it surprised me though that matlab help wasn't clearer on this point. When I design code, I make it to work with every parameter user could choose... 10, 1000, 2000...